# mails delivered but courier-imap refuses connection

Tags: imap, courier

My mailserver delivers mails successfull in Maildir format. But I cannot connect to courier through IMAP. It refuses the connection. The firewall port 143 is opened. The server is running openSUSE 13.2.
Here are my config file `/etc/courier/imapd` (removed comments for better view):

```
ADDRESS=***
PORT=143
MAXDAEMONS=40                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
MAXPERIP=20                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
PIDFILE=/run/imapd.pid
TCPDOPTS="-nodnslookup -noidentlookup"
LOGGEROPTS="-name=imapd"
IMAP_CAPABILITY="IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS CHILDREN NAMESPACE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES SORT QUOTA IDLE"
IMAP_KEYWORDS=1
IMAP_ACL=1
IMAP_CAPABILITY_ORIG="IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS CHILDREN NAMESPACE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES SORT QUOTA AUTH=CRAM-MD5 AUTH=CRAM-SHA1 AUTH=CRAM-SHA256 IDLE"
IMAP_PROXY=0
IMAP_PROXY_FOREIGN=0
IMAP_IDLE_TIMEOUT=60
IMAP_MAILBOX_SANITY_CHECK=1
IMAP_CAPABILITY_TLS="$IMAP_CAPABILITY AUTH=PLAIN"
IMAP_CAPABILITY_TLS_ORIG="$IMAP_CAPABILITY_ORIG AUTH=PLAIN"
IMAP_DISABLETHREADSORT=0
IMAP_CHECK_ALL_FOLDERS=0
IMAP_OBSOLETE_CLIENT=0
IMAP_UMASK=022
IMAP_ULIMITD=65536
IMAP_USELOCKS=1
IMAP_SHAREDINDEXFILE=/etc/courier/shared/index
IMAP_ENHANCEDIDLE=0
IMAP_TRASHFOLDERNAME=Trash
IMAP_EMPTYTRASH=Trash:7
IMAP_MOVE_EXPUNGE_TO_TRASH=0
SENDMAIL=/usr/sbin/sendmail
HEADERFROM=X-IMAP-Sender
IMAPDSTART=YES
MAILDIRPATH=Maildir
```

Please tell me, if you need any other file to solve the problem.

Comment: Is courier-imap started, do you see `couriertcp` processes, does `sudo lsof -i tcp:imap` return anything?

Comment: yes, it returns listen on my domain.